Powershell - last time a script was executed
I have some old .ps1 scripts created a few years ago and that are just there standing by, they don't seem to have been executed recently.
Is there any way to know when was the last time they were actually executed?
Thank you!

you can check the date when the file was accessed, but this would include opening in an editor, say

Does the script perform any actions that you could check for timestamps? E.g. if it deletes files from a temp folder then the oldest file currently in that folder must have been created after the script last ran so that puts an upper limit on the last run date. If it creates a database record, what’s the timestamp on the most recent record? If it reboots a server, the last startup / login event in the event log will give you a timestamp for the script, etc. Obviously, this won’t work if the script doesn’t leave any timestamped side-effects…

Assuming you have PowerShell ScriptBlock logging enabled you can check for executions of a given script by including the path in your filter when using Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath:
Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\old\files -Filter *.ps1 |ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_
    $xPathFilter = '*[EventData[Data[@Name="Path"] = "{0}"]]' -f $file.FullName
    $lastExecutionEvent = Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath $xPathFilter -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($lastExecutionEvent) {
        Write-Host "$($file.Name) was last executed at $($lastExecutionEvent.TimeCreated)"
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Unable to locate execution of $($file.Name) in event logs"
    }
}


Now, "not appearing in the logs" is not the same as "never happened", it just means it hasn't happened since the time of the last entry in the event log.
To check the oldest event in the log (thus establishing the time window for which you have logs), invoke the following command and note the TimeCreated value:
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational -MaxEvents 1 -Oldest



Mathias' helpful answer is probably the most robust solution, within the following constraints:

It requires script-block logging to have been enabled prior to when the script was last invoked.

It is limited by when the relevant event log was last cleared.



As yacc mentions in a comment,  a simple - but not robust - alternative solution is to check the script file's last-accessed timestamp.[1]
(Get-Item C:\path\to\your\script.ps1).LastAccessTime

The caveat is that any access to the content of the target .ps1 file is recorded in this timestamp - not just the file's execution.
That is, actions such as opening the file in an editor or listing its content with Get-Content update the timestamp too, leading to false positives.

[1] Note that not all file-systems record last-accessed timestamps, and on Windows / NTFS file-systems, where such timestamps are maintained, they may not be up to date - see this SU answer.

U could try if the cmd promt might has that information:
dir /TA "path\to\your\script.ps1"

